# Speed up or avoid using importScripts in WebWorker

Tags: javascript, optimization, ecmascript-6, web-worker

I'm writing a program that executes arbitrary user-provided code in web-workers. I'm constructing the worker code as a blob with the user-provided code inserted into it dynamically, and then instantiating the worker from that blob. I'd initially tried just eval-ing the code from the worker, but had to switch to this approach because i need to be able to see stack traces & line numbers for errors. As part of my web-worker, several scripts need to be imported using importScripts(), both from a CDN and from my own server. Since i now need to instantiate a new worker every time i run the code, the script imports take a really long time at the beginning of each run. Is there any way to cut down on this time? Possibly by importing all the necessary scripts just once for all future workers? Or, would in-lining the scripts help substantially?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

- create a worker that imports the scripts you need
- then let the worker wait for "execute code" message
- this message will contain user's code
- worker will convert the code using `new Function("string")`
- then the function will be executed

It's what I did when testing some code that is already running here: http://darker.github.io/asteroids/demo-elastic-bounce/

You can edit the function while web worker is running.

Although you can try to in-line the scripts that will have flaws:

- ugly code
- possible CORS issues